# how to concatenate numpy array of different shape

Tags: python, numpy

I have two `NumPy` arrays of shape: (Batch, H, W, Canal). I would like to concat these arrays in one array, but they have different shapes `[209, 450, 450, 24]` and `[209, 112, 112]`.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What is the expected shape of the concatenated array? If the arrays are converted from image data, you should resize the images first, then create arrays with consistent sizes.

Comment: Hello, actually  I am extracting feature maps from an efficient net model pretrained on imagenet, thus each numpy array has a different shape, only the batch size is consistent each time (because of convolution2D). 
I would like to concatenate some of these features maps, but I don't have a "target shape". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to concatenate vectors with different sizes is to fill the smaller one with zeros, so that it is the same shape as the bigger.

```py
bigger = np.random.uniform(size=(209, 450, 450, 24)) # should be your input
smaller = np.random.uniform(size=(209, 112, 112))
s = np.zeros(bigger.shape[:-1])
s[:smaller.shape[0], :smaller.shape[1], :smaller.shape[2]] = smaller
s = s[..., np.newaxis] # reshaping to (209, 450, 450, 1)
result = np.concatenate([bigger, s], axis=-1)
```

But if they are images, you should use a image library to resize the images to the correct shape.

```
import PIL.Image

bigger = np.random.uniform(size=(209, 450, 450, 24)) # should be your input
smaller = np.random.uniform(size=(209, 112, 112))
s = np.zeros(bigger.shape[:-1])
for i in range(bigger.shape[0]):
    s[i] = np.array(PIL.Image.fromarray(smaller[i]).resize((s.shape[2], s.shape[1])))
s = s[..., np.newaxis] # reshaping to (209, 450, 450, 1)
result = np.concatenate([bigger, s], axis=-1)
```